# Set order of rows in Pivot Table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am currently using a Pivot table which is linked to several tables in other sheets in a workbook. However I need to the rows to be ordered as per the Hierarchy I determine when I enter the data. I have the position number in one of the source tables but need to use that data to set the position within the pivot table using some VBA code. I'm not sure if this is possible so any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pivot tables are sorted based on the fields being used for aggregation and calculation.  You can generally apply the the sorts you want on the resulting Pivot Table.  It may be possible to recover the desired sorting, but it is nearly impossible to say without more specific information: how are you currently trying to sort and how does it not work?  What is the nature of the underlying data and "hierarchy"?  Can you share a picture or summary of the data?  Add a link to your post or a comment and I will [edit] it into the post.